D3 curve to ignore missing values, instead of default them to 0
I have two time series data, plotted on a line diagram, using D3 curves.  The original data is like the following (when are actual Date objects):
[{when: '2024-05-01', a: 654, b: 456},
 {when: '2024-05-02', a: 566, b: 546},
 {when: '2024-05-03', a: 654, b: 456},
 {when: '2024-05-04', a: 456, b: 564},
 {when: '2024-05-05', a: 564, b: 665}]

I plot them using the following code (using d3.curveMonotoneX, in this case to plot values from the property a):
const line = d3.line()
    .x(d => xScale(d.when))
    .y(d => yScale(d.a))
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);
g.append('path')
    .attr('d', line(data))
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', orange);

This gives me something like the following:

My question is: is it possible to support drawing one line, where some of the slots do not have a value for a specific property.  Something like the following (note that the objects in the array lack a couple of values for the red line, it just behaves as if these slots did not exist at all):

If I use the D3 code above, it behaves like if missing values were equal to 0:

Is it possible to tell d3.curve* to ignore missing values all together?  Rather than filtering the original list just in case and create a new array for each curve...
EDIT
When I read line.defined() method doc (thanks @mark,) I thought that was what I was looking for.  Unfortunately, it creates multiple segments in case any point is missing.  For instance, if the red line is missing the 1 point in the middle, it looks like this:

When what I'd like is just to consider that the point does not exist at all, and behave like that record was not in the array in the first place.

You are looking for the defined method of d3's line generator.  In your second graph b is missing its second and fourth data point, so maybe the data looks like this craziness:
[{when: '2024-05-01', a: 654, b: 456},
 {when: '2024-05-02', a: 566, b: undefined},
 {when: '2024-05-03', a: 654, b: 456},
 {when: '2024-05-04', a: 456, b: null},
 {when: '2024-05-05', a: 564, b: 665}]

Your line generator could look like:
const line = d3.line()
  .defined(d => d.b !== undefined && d.b !== null)
  .x(d => xScale(d.when))
  .y(d => yScale(d.b))
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);


Thank you!  I thought that was it.  Almost :-)  I added my comment as an edit on the post, so I could add a screenshot.

Your Data:
[{when: '2024-05-01', a: 654, b: 456},
 {when: '2024-05-02', a: 566, b: undefined},
 {when: '2024-05-03', a: 654, b: 456},
 {when: '2024-05-04', a: 456, b: undefined},
 {when: '2024-05-05', a: 564, b: 665}]

Should work easily if u split the data:
const line1 = [{when: '2024-05-01', a: 654},
 {when: '2024-05-02', a: 566},
 {when: '2024-05-03', a: 654},
 {when: '2024-05-04', a: 456},
 {when: '2024-05-05', a: 564}]

const line2 = [{when: '2024-05-01', b: 456},
 {when: '2024-05-03', b: 456},
 {when: '2024-05-05', b: 665}]

or use a filter d.filter(x => x.b !== undefined)
